# How to import Django main project urls file from separate app?

Tags: python, django

I have a Django project called 'myproject' and a separate app called 'myapp'. 'myapp' is completely independent from 'myproject'.

I want to be able to import the urls.py file in 'myproject' from 'myapp', is this possible? If so, how can I do that?

The problem is that I want `myapp` to stay independent, so I can install it on different projects without having to edit anything.
So I can't simply do:

```
import myproject.urls as urls
```

Comment: `myapp` needs to be on your pythonpath (i.e. `pip install myapp`), and added to `INSTALLED_APPS` as a django app

Answer (score 1):

For example, the "django-allauth" app is completely independent, and it has a `urls.py` file. So in you `settings.py`, you load the app:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...,
    'django-allauth',
    ...,
)
```

and then in your project's `urls.py` you include the app's urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...,
    url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    ...,
]
```

See the Django basic Tutorial:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial03/

Comment: The problem is that I don't know what the project name is, the app should be reusable among projects..

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to import the file, and assuming you have the app installed correctly, then you should just be able to do

```
from myproject import urls
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't know what the project name is, the app should be reusable among projects..

Comment: Ah, I see. I'm not sure if there's a way of accessing anything within the project package if you don't know the project name.